# Excel: check all columns have a different value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to know how to compare for every row that their (numeric) columns have different values or all of them are equal, and get the result (either a boolean or a 0/1) in another column. Something like:

```
      colA colB colC   Result
row1  12   12   45     false
row2  67   67   67     true
```

How could I write this formula concisely in Microsoft Excel? Note that the number of columns may vary and at least I have about 30 columns, so I don't want to name the columns in the formula, but write something like a `for`

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to test only numbers, what about?

```
=MIN(B1:B30)=MAX(B1:B30)
```

(if your range goes from 1 to 30)

`for` doesn't exist in Excel formula, the best way to deal with a `for loop` would be to use array formulas but this is not appropriated here.

what you may look for is a [dynamic range](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/DynamicRanges.htm) but i can't see a way to implement it easily in your case

[EDIT] new formula thanks to Excelll's comment

```
=AND(MIN(B1:B30)=MAX(B1:B30),COUNTBLANK(B1:B30)=0)
```

Comment: Very true! Nice way to do it, thanks. I had actually already come up with another formula myself: `=IF(STDEV(A3:D3)=0,1,0)` //in any case I wanted to do it for columns, not rows

Comment: @jmcejuela: your formula relies on the same idea, nice one too :)

Comment: Note that this formula will overlook blank cells.  For example, "1 1 _ 1" would return TRUE.

Comment: @Excelll: indeed, i'll build another formula that will take care of this case

Comment: @JMax Actually either ignoring or checking empty values could be seen as features, and you give both formulas. Accepted! :)

Answer (score 3):

If blank cells within a row are not an issue, @JMax offers a clever solution. However, if you want a blank cell to return "FALSE", you can use the following array formula:

```
=AND(EXACT(A1,B1:C1))
```

Enter this as an array formula by pressing Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

Comment: It works on my Excel 2007.  Maybe it's a version issue?  Either way, for you project "=" works just fine.  {=AND(A1=B1:C1)}